# Which preposition: "Write on/at/to this address?"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

My exam included this fill-in-the-blank question:

> Please write __ this address.  (on/at/to)

I filled the blank with *on*.

Is that correct?

Comment: In fact, no preposition is required here at all. *Please write this address.*

Comment: @choster Is that a British usage? In AmE we would say "to."

Comment: yep.Its British.

Comment: A preposition **is** required here - the context is an exam, and the option to omit a preposition is not given. The meaning would change were no preposition used: _Please write this address_ = (approximately) _Please print this address._ It is not traditional UK usage to 'write someone' (unless followed by a direct object, such as  'a letter'), and certainly not to 'write somewhere'. In BrE we would also say 'to'.

Comment: I realize the context is an exam, which is why I left a comment and not an answer. But I'm American and also find it perfectly natural to say things like *If you have questions or comments, please write this address.*

Comment: @choster *Please write this address* is very definitely NOT British and, to me, would prompt the response *Where do you want me to write it?*, meaning you want me to write it on a form, on an envelope, or where?

Comment: @TrevorD Do you say "Dial this number" or "Email this account"?

Comment: @choster Yes, but *write* can be used in the sense of *write down* ("write down this address") or *write to* ("write to this address"), as well as in the sense of *write a letter*, *write an e-mail*, *write a report*, etc.. Without the *to*, I would automatically interpret it as *write down* or *write a letter*, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can **write on** paper or any surface, such as a hand or on a wall.
You can also **write on** a subject or topic according to this website: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/write+on (but I'm not entirely convinced).

So "Please write **on** this address" I would interpret to mean the inscriber has to write *over* a pre-typed address. "On" in this case indicates place. The request sounds odd to me but from a grammatical point of view it is arguably correct.

As for using the preposition "at" I would consider the sentence to be incomplete. A direct object is needed.

"Please write to me/him/her/us/them **at** this address"

My preferred answer would be: "Please write **to** this address" You are asked to communicate and transfer your message from one place (presumably your home) to another ("this address"). 
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to?s=t

Answer (score 0):

If a preposition is required, "to" would be the preferred. "At" would also be acceptable, although possibly formal/archaic.